# Defining a custom native event on React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to define a custom event in my React Native app on Android. I have native View, which has a native Button. When the button is pressed, I want to send a message to my React Native Component to show a modal screen.

I have followed the examples but don't understand all the elements, and have done a bit of guesswork in my attempt.

In my ViewManager class:

```
public class MyViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<MyView> {

    // Contructor etc...

    @Override
    protected MyView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
        //... Create and return the view 
    }

    /**
     * Custom native events
     * @return Map of additional events
     */
    @Override
    public @Nullable
    Map getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
        return MapBuilder.of(
                "showModal",
                MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onPressModalButton")
        );
    }
}
```

The custom View:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
    }

    public void showModal() {
        Log.d("MyView", "showModal");

        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("showModal", "onPressModalButton");
        ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
        reactContext.getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class).receiveEvent(
                getId(),
                "showModal", 
                event);
    }
}
```

So I would like, each time `showModal` is called, for a JS event to be triggered to that I can show a modal view in the React Native app.

In my React Component I have:

```
  class MyNativeComponent extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
      ...View.propTypes,
      onPressModalButton: React.PropTypes.func
    }
    render() {
      return <MyView {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  const MyView = requireNativeComponent('MyView', MyNativeComponent, { nativeOnly: {showModal: true} })

  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._showModal = this._showModal.bind(this);
    }

    _showModal(event: Event) {

      console.log("showModal from React!")
        if (!this.props.onPressModalButton) {
          return;
        }
      this.props.onPressModalButton(event.nativeEvent.showModal);
    }

    //...
  }
```

What I don't understand is how the mapping works, and how I can define an event (like onChange in the [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html)).

Comment: Thanks to this post for pointing me in the right direction. [I've tried to put together a comprehensive solution on a related post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207488/383414)

Comment: Hi, what method did you added SetOnclickListener?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't show my `render` method and that was where the missing part was. I missed out the prop that passes in the event handling method, in this case `onPressModalButton={this_.showModal}`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      < MyNativeComponent style={{flex: 1}} onPressModalButton={this._showModal} />
    </View>
  )
}
```