# "bubbling" vs "direct" events in React Native Android custom view

Tags: android, react-native

React Native Android custom views are able to declare events in 2 different ways in a `ViewManager` subclass :

- "bubbling" events via `getExportedCustomBubblingEventTypeConstants()`
- "direct" events via `getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants()`

What is the difference between these 2 types of event?

If I am trying to send an event from an Android custom view `onClick(View v)` method up to the JS representation of my view, which of these methods would I use to declare my custom event name?

---

**Follow up:** I ended up [using a "direct" event to send a click from my Android view back to my JS component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207488/383414). This worked very well, but I would still like to know what the "bubbling" event is all about.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207488/2881112
I was able to get a grasp on handling native events in Android.

After experimenting a lot this is what I found out.

There are basically two types of events

- direct events - this only seems to affect the custom native component
- bubbling events - this event if not handled by the native component gets bubbled up to the parent components till its handled.

Example:

if I define `getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants` for onClick event on my custom view component `CustomView`

Then this works

```
 <CustomView onClick={() => console.log("Hello")}/>
```

but not this

```
<Pressable onPress={() => console.log("Hello")}>
   <CustomView/>
</Pressable>
```

but if I use

`getExportedCustomBubblingEventTypeConstants`

Then both of these work

```
 <CustomView onClick={() => console.log("Hello")}/>
```

and

```
<Pressable onPress={() => console.log("Hello")}>
   <CustomView/>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: My experience is right to the opposite. Then react native component couldn't receive a bubbling event but the direct event works well.