# How to understand event callbacks from Android in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to send some event with additional data from my Android module to JS part. I read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html#events but the proposed code did not work for me, dont know why. Then I read this SO post [Creating Custom UI component for android on React Native. How to send data to JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739670/creating-custom-ui-component-for-android-on-react-native-how-to-send-data-to-js/44207488#44207488) and I finally managed to send onClick event from my Android View and receive callback in JS. However, when I change name of the event from onClick to whatever else, it stops working. Ok, I can live with the onClick name but I have to send some additional data (as in official docs with `message` property), but when I try to read that data, its undefined. Here is corresponding code

Sending event:

```
  WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
  event.putString("url", url);
  ((ReactContext) getContext()).getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class)
     .receiveEvent(getId(), "onClick", event);
```

with registered direct event name like this

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
    return MapBuilder.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("onClick",
                    MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onClick"))
            .build();
}
```

Receiving in JS:

```
class MySuperView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick(event: Event) {
        this.props.onClick(event.nativeEvent.url)
    }

    render() {
        return <MyView {...this.props} onClick={this.onClick} />;
    }
}
```

and then use of this component in my app:

```
<MySuperView
            onClick={(url) => {
                console.log(url)
            }}
        />
```

However, my log says `undefined` .. I tried to change `url` to `message` but still nothing. When I print whole event.nativeEvent, its huge object that does not fit in one logcat message so i cant read all of its content.

Disclaimer: I am Android Developer and I am just starting to learn RN + JS, so maybe I am missing some fundamental stuff, but I did everything whats inside official docs and nothing works.

So my questions are - why I cant use different name than `onClick` and why I cant read my `url` property from nativeEvent like in docs?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: The only thing looking fishy is the "onClick" name, try another name. Because "onClick" is actually one of React's built-in prop names. When I tried using 2 "onClick" strings in getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants like your code above, I got error "Error: Unsupported top level event type "message" dispatched". When I changed the 1st "onClick" to "message", it worked.